# how to enable remote access to my local server

Tags: webserver, router, port-forwarding

I have Apache,php,mysql server set up in ubuntu. and I can open my app at 127.0.0.1. but now I want another machine any where in the world to access my homepage, so I find out my global ip address is something like : 90.168.23.xx. but when this is typed in the web browser, it comes out with a page of my local router configuration page, so my question is is it possible to do that, if yes, how shall I go about it? thanks for help.

update: please note that I don't have a fixed ip address. I just want another machine access it temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to log in to your router and forward the ports (I.e. 80, 443 etc) to your web server. How exactly is dependent on your router, but chances are there'll be a tab called "Port Forwarding".

You'll need to give your web server a static IP on your network for this to be remotely reliable.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. this makes sense. but I could find something like forwarding nowhere.

Comment: What is the make and model of your router?

Comment: http://portforward.com/

Comment: it is ZYxel  P-2602HW-D1A.
I was also googling this fowarding issues. the portfoward is a great reference. thanks guys.

Comment: ok, I find the port forwarding tab with my router. there is a direct tutorial about this.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMRqbZRjdn4. thanks   for help.